# Eventsearch with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, events, label, flags

I have a dataframe and I would like to creat a column with event labels. If a condition is true, then the event would get a number. But I want to give the same event label if the successive values are events. Do you have any idea? I tried to use .apply and .rolling, but without any success.

DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Signal_1' : [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]})

    Signal_1  ExpectedColumn
0          0             NaN 
1          0             NaN
2          0             NaN
3          1               1
4          1               1
5          0             NaN
6          0             NaN
7          1               2
8          1               2
9          1               2
10         1               2
11         0             NaN
12         0             NaN
13         0             NaN
14         1               3
15         1               3
16         1               3
17         1               3
18         1               3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it. First create the countup flag, and then perform a cumsum. Then correct it with the NaN values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Signal_1' : [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]})

# Only count up when the previous sample = 0, and the current sample = 1
df["shift"] = df["Signal_1"].shift(1)
df["countup"] = np.where((df["Signal_1"] == 1) & (df["shift"] == 0),1,0)

# Cumsum the countup flag and set to NaN when sample = 0
df["result"] = df["countup"].cumsum()
df["result"] = np.where(df["Signal_1"] == 0, np.NaN, df["result"] )
```